# PHP for Multiple conditions?

Tags: php, for-loop, count

im trying to make a function that generates a menu from array with menu name and menu icon, but the real question is how to make for statement with 2 conditions like:

```
for($i=0; $i<count($names); $i++ && $a=0; $a<count($images); $a++)
```

I tried to put one more for statement into the current one but then it outputs everything double.

As requested:

```
$names[] = $row['game_name'];
        $images[] = $row['game_icon'];
        }
          for($i=0; $i<count($names); $i++ ) {


        echo ' 
         <li class="has-submenu">

        <a href="#">'.$names[$i].'</a>

        </li>
        ';

          }
```

This is the code, I have also to count $names[] = $row['game_name']; in the same for condition.

Comment: while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
   
  
  $names[] = $row['game_name'];
        $images[] = $row['game_icon'];
  }
    for($i=0; $i<count($names); $i++ ) {
     
      
        echo ' 
   <li class="has-submenu">
   
  <a href="#">'.$names[$i].'</a>
   
  </li>
  ';
 
    }

Comment: I need to count 2 arrays which contains names and images, then output these arrays one by one like $array[1], $array[2] and so on.

Comment: Are there the same number of images as names?

Comment: no, this is why I have to count $images and $name arrays individually.

Comment: $names[] = $row['game_name'];
         
  }
    for($i=0; $i<count($names); $i++ ) {
     
      
        echo ' 
   <li class="has-submenu">
   
  <a href="#">'.$names[$i].'</a>
   
  </li>
  ';
 
    }

Comment: As you are adding an image and a name each time, there should be an equal number of them, so use `$images[$i]` in the loop to access the image.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is using nested  for()

```
  for($i=0; $i<count($names); $i++){
    for( $a=0; $a<count($images); $a++) {
      .....
    }
  }
```

Comment: *I tried to put one more for statement into the current one but then it outputs everything double.* - so I assume this is what they have already tried.